# How do you make 2 sets of unique coordinates in python

Tags: python

So basically I have to get 15 unique coordinates all different from each other but 10 of them in 1 set and the remaining 5 in another set.

```
  cords_set = set()
  while len(cords_set) < 10:
      x, y = 7, 0
      while (x, y) == (7, 0):
           x, y = randint(0, len(board) - 1), randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
      cords_set.add((x, y))



    cords_set2 = set()
    while len(cords_set2) < 5:
        x, y = 7, 0
        while (x,y) == (7, 0):
            x,y = randint(0, len(board) - 1), randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
        cords_set2.add((x,y))
```

This is the code so far but some of the coordinates from cords_set are the same in cords_set2 and I want all of them to be different.

Comment: Then add code to check if each pair is in `coords_set` before adding it to `coords_set2`. Also: why not simply assign the two `randint`s straight to `x, y` without faffing around with `(7, 0)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe seems like OP used a code from my answer in the posted dupe, which in turn is based on the logic of that question's OP's code.